# Go limit slice to max elements

Tags: go

how can i set slice max elements?

I want only 50 Elements and not over 50...

This is my Code

```
var result []*HistoryData
func convertHistoryResults(currenthashrate int64, online int64, offline int64, now int64) []*HistoryData {
    history := HistoryData{}
    history.CurrentHashrate = currenthashrate
    history.Online = online
    history.Offline = offline
    history.Timestamp = now
    result = append(result, &history)
    return result
}
```

Its working, but its pushing endless elements to it... so i have a very long slice. I want to set a maxiumum of 50. So i tried

```
result = append(result[:50], &history)
```

So that i overwrite everytime the 50th element, but idk thats not working :/

I want to cut the first element off when reaching 50th element and set 51, when cutting 1 off... so the newest is at the end and the oldest cutting off

Comment: Slice is dynamically sized, so every call to append will append the element to the end of the slice. If you want to limit to certain size, use array or check the slice for length and return error when size exceeds

Comment: I can't say for sure, since I don't see the whole picture of what you're trying to do, but if you're further processing the result slice you could consider to use buffered channels instead.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in functionality like this. You'll just need to check:

```
var result []*HistoryData
func convertHistoryResults(currenthashrate int64, online int64, offline int64, now int64) ([]*HistoryData, error) {
    if len(result) >= 50 {
        return nil, errors.New("result too long")
    }
    history := HistoryData{}
    history.CurrentHashrate = currenthashrate
    history.Online = online
    history.Offline = offline
    history.Timestamp = now
    result = append(result, &history)
    return result, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you, but it will allocate memory with each append, so make sure you don't run into performance problems with this code:

```
i := 0
slice := []int{}
limit := 5
for i < 30 {
    if len(slice) > limit {
        slice = append(slice[1:], i)
    } else {
        slice = append(slice, i)
    }
    fmt.Println(slice)
    i++
}
```